# how much can HTML prerender, prerender if the page has a lot of php and sql based logic

Tags: php, html

I have a web app I made for work and it uses a lot of sql queries to work, so when you click a link that link might be for an order that the next page will use the `id` to search the SQL table to build the next page in php.

so if I use prerender will it load everything that's not php code or will it do anything at all?

prerender example code:

`echo "<link rel='prerender' 'order.php'>";`

should prerender order.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prerender directive is run by browsers, so the result is the same as when you go to order.php in your browser directly. It won't and shouldn't work with forms or the like where you need user input. Imagine this technique saying "You probably want to go to this page next, open it in a new background tab and switch to it later if you want". The only difference being the browser opening the new page for you and you will see it as soon as you click on a link that leads to that page. For example, google could implement this for the first search result. The browser loads the page even before the user clicks the link and shows it when the user actually does.

Browser support is relatively low BTW. So far only Chrome, IE11, Edge and Opera support this. Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=prerender

Comment: thanks, so just to reword it in my own words you answer is, if the result isn't static, the next page will render 0% of its content? 

It won't render the plain HTML and then do the php functions when you click?

Comment: The browser doesn't distinguish between static and dynamic pages. It asks the server to serve HTML and the server handles the PHP and MySQL part. That said, your PHP and MySQL code will get executed before the user gets to see the page or even without the user visiting the page at all. But this does execute all PHP and stuff. Only JavaScript is not run until the user gets to see the page. If your next page doesn't render any content without user input, then the browser will get an empty or error page. Same as if you go to the page in browser directly by URL.